# Python path in VS Code on Linux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So, this has been covered a number of times already, and there's some good documentation on how things are supposed to work [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable). Except: nothing seems to work for me! How do I debug this, what am I missing? I've tried the following things:

- set `PYTHONPATH` in `.env` in the root of my workspace
- add `"python.envFile": ".env"` to `.vscode/settings.json`
- move `.env` to `.vscode/env`, update `python.envFile` to reflect
- remove all the env business, add `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` to `.vscode/settings.json`
- use a workspace config with a `settings` key, repeat the steps above
- just give in and run `PYTHONPATH=directory code .`

All of the above is completely ignored, pylint keeps on complaining. I am getting a bit frustrated. What am I missing here!

Comment: Also, I tried using `export PYTHONPATH=...`. That at least propagates the path to the python interpreter in the terminal. The least of my problems, but nice to see that at least _something_ is listening to me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, cause found. Even outside of VS Code `pylint` was acting up. Source of the problem: the top-level dir also contained an `__init__.py` file, messing up all sorts of things. Remove that file and it starts working...